# modifying the addition of two binary numbers in my code

Tags: c++

i am trying to add binary numbers in my program but im not happy with what i have,my code adds binary numbers like this

```
1010
+1111
```

but i want to change it so that it when i enter a binary number like 100010001 it should add
like this 
     1010
    +1111
my code automatically adds because of the two arrays and the values in the array i want to enter the binary number from the keybord and it should do like the above example
this is my code

```
int main()
{
    int a[4];
    int b[4];
    int carry=0;
    int result[5];


    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=0;
    a[2]=0;
    a[3]=1;

    b[0]=1;
    b[1]=1;
    b[2]=1;
    b[3]=1;

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {

        if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==3)
        {
        result[i]=1;
        carry=1;
        }
        if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==2)
        {
        result[i]=0;
        carry=1;
        }
        if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==1)
        {
        result[i]=1;
        carry=0;
        }
        if(a[i]+b[i]+carry==0)
        {
        result[i]=0;
        carry=0;
        }


    }
    result[4]=carry;
    for(int j=4; j>=0; j--)
    {
        cout<<result[j];

    }
    cout<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

im a newbie so many if there are mistakes please correct me and give me your best advise thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve.. pls explain what you would like to do more clearly

Comment: Do you want to add binary numbers of any arbitrary length other than four bit numbers?

Comment: ok if you notice my code its adding the binary that are already in the arrays but i want to change that i should enter the binary numbers using my keyboard secondly i do want to enter a binary like 10001111 it should add like 1000 + 1111,hope i am clear :)

Comment: @NeonGlow yes something like that

Comment: Will this help anyway. http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1587/2010/6/scanf-adding-binary-numbers-4.htm

Comment: Break this down into two problems. Try to solve one of them. If you can't solve it, break it down into two problems. Try to solve one of them. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing I see is that you are not starting at the right-most bit. Addition with binary numbers is the same as with real base 10 numbers in that you start at the right and work towards the left, whatever bit you have left, you append it to the beginning of your sum.

So with yours:

9 + 15

1001 + 1111

i = 3
--> [][][][0] -->carry = 1

i = 2 --->[][][0][0] --->carry = 1

i = 1 --->[][0][0][0] --->carry = 1

i = 0 --->[1][0][0][0] --->carry = 1

OH noes we ran out of space

So append the carry to the front of the sum:

[1][1][0][0][0] ---> 24

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a pretty trivial problem.

How to add two binary numbers in c++. what is the logic of it.

For adding two binary numbers, a and b. You can use the following equations to do so.

sum = a xor b

carry = ab

This is the equation for a Half Adder.

Now to implement this, you may need to understand how a Full Adder works.

sum = a xor b xor c

carry = ab+bc+ca

Since you store your binary numbers in int array, you might want to understand bitwise operation. You can use ^ for XOR,| operator for OR, & operator for AND.

Here is a sample code to calculate the sum.

for(i = 0; i < 8 ; i++)
{

sum[i] = ((a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ c); // c is carry

c = ((a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] &c)) | (b[i] & c);

}